# Си, упорядочивание таблицы

Tags: c, сортировка

Подпрограмма создает неупорядоченную таблицу, а нужно, что бы она сразу создавала упорядоченную. Не понимаю, как это сделать :(

На вход в программе подается шифр (8 символов), название и количество.
Думаю, проще всего будет упорядочить по количеству.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать

Вот функция добавления в таблицу из .h файла, остальным, я думаю, нет смысла забивать место в посте. Если нужно, добавлю весь остальной код.
Для неупорядоченной все идеально работает.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const int N = 10000;
extern int num;

struct table // таблица
{
char code[9]; //шифр
char name[255]; //название
int numb; // количество
};

// функция добавления элемента в таблицу
void table_add(struct table *t, char *code, char *name, int numb)

{
int i;
int flag = 0;
for (i = 0; i < num && !flag; i++)
{
    if (!strcmp(code, t[i].code))
    {
        flag++;
        t[i].numb += numb;
    }
}
if (!flag)
    {
    strcpy(t[num].code, code);
    strcpy(t[num].name, name);
    t[num].numb = numb;
    num++;
    }
}
```

Входные данные имеют вид: 123dh678 iphone 100

8символов - шифр, название продукта и количество произведенного продукта.
Все это в main читается из файла и добавляется в таблицу с помощью функции table_add.

Упорядочить думаю будет лучше и легче всего по numb (количество произведенного продукта)

Comment: Упорядоченная таблица достигается либо сортировкой, либо начальными условиями. Из вашего текста вообще ничего не понятно. Покажите примеры того, что на входе, и того, что ожидается на выходе, и т.д.

Comment: @0andriy  извиняюсь, чет тупанул. Сейчас исправлю пост.

Comment: @0andriy добавил. Если нужно, могу вставить и весь остальной код, но там около 200 строк.

Comment: Все еще ничего не понятно. `На вход в программе подается шифр (8 цифр)` далее по тексту: `Входные данные имеют вид: 123dh678  iphone 100`. Так цифр или символов?

Comment: @Eanmos Там могут быть и цифры и символы, без разницы. 34248582 или fdskfksk или 135fds5f

Comment: Уточните условие. *Написал программу на **неупорядоченной** таблице, а нужно на упорядоченной*. Не понимаю, что значит упорядочить таблицу. Наверное вы имели в виду упорядочить массив таблиц?

Answer (score 0):

*В качестве функции сортировки была взята простейшая "Сортировка пузырьком", найденная на просторах интернета.*

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NUMBER_TABLES 100

int current_num_tables = 0;

struct Table
{
    char code[9];
    char name[255];
    int  numb;
};

void swap_table(struct Table* t, const int num1, const int num2)
{
    char buf_code[9];
    char buf_name[255];
    int  buf_numb;

    strcpy(buf_code, t[num2].code);
    strcpy(buf_name, t[num2].name);
    buf_numb = t[num2].numb;

    strcpy(t[num2].code, t[num1].code);
    strcpy(t[num2].name, t[num1].name);
    t[num2].numb = t[num1].numb;

    strcpy(t[num1].code, buf_code);
    strcpy(t[num1].name, buf_name);
    t[num1].numb = buf_numb;
}

void add_table(struct Table* t, const char* _code, const char* _name, const int _numb)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < current_num_tables; ++i)
    {
        if (!strcmp(_code, t[i].code)) {
            t[i].numb += _numb;
            return; 
        }
    }

    strcpy(t[current_num_tables].code, _code);
    strcpy(t[current_num_tables].name, _name);
    t[current_num_tables].numb = _numb;
    current_num_tables++;
    return;
}


void bubbleSort(struct Table *t, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (t[j].numb > t[j-1].numb) {
                swap_table(t, j, j-1);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Table tb[MAX_NUMBER_TABLES];

    add_table(tb, "1code", "1name", 1);
    add_table(tb, "2code", "2name", 2);
    add_table(tb, "3code", "3name", 3);
    add_table(tb, "4code", "4name", 4);
    add_table(tb, "5code", "5name", 5);
    add_table(tb, "5code", "5name", 15);


    bubbleSort(tb, current_num_tables);

    for (int i = 0; i < current_num_tables; ++i)
        printf("table[%d] :: %s %s %d\n", i, tb[i].code, tb[i].name, tb[i].numb);

    return 0;
}
```

### Комментарии к коду

1. Названия структур принято писать с большой буквы:

   ```
   Было: struct table
   Стало: struct Table
   ```
2. Стандарт C11 разрешает объявлять переменные в заголовке цикла:

   ```
   Было: int i;
         ...
         for (i = 0; i < num ...; i++)

   Стало: for (int i = 0; i < ...; ++i)
              ^^^^^
   ```
3. Чтобы досрочно выйти из `void` функции можно использовать `return;` (тем самым избавившись от переменно `flag`):

Comment: Спасибо, сделал с пузырьковой сортировкой, но препод меня послал и сказал, что нужно как то сразу создавать упорядоченную таблицу в функции добавления элемента :(